# Timed event only executes once

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having some trouble putting this up to work.

I've got an approval system where the user clicks on a link to approve or disapprove a post.

All the content is loaded with ajax calls, so when the user does the click, an info window pops alerting the user to success or error and then, reloads the content.

The script is working, but, only on the first click. On the second click, the message flashes and disappears almost instantanely before the content is reloaded.

Could someone help me with this?

Here's the code

```
function activateSource(id) {
    $("#confirm-activate-" + id).toggle('slow');
    $(document).on('click', '.confirm-activate', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                "source-id": id
            },
            url: "modules/source/activatesource.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#confirmation-response").html(data);
                dismissAlert();
            }
        })
    });
}

function dismissAlert() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#confirmation-response").hide('blind', function () {
            loadSourceContent()
        }, 500);
    }, 2500);
}
```

Comment: Content is PHP - driven. A fiddle is not the best view for this, so I think.

Comment: what are  confirm-activate-id and confirmation-response? ALso, what does loadSourceContent() do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if everything is working fine except the message flashing and disappearing after first try, you have a problem with the [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function. You need to display 'confirmation-response' before you call hide again otherwise it just flickers.

Try using this -

```
function dismissAlert() {
    // Show the response
    $("#confirmation-response").show( 'blind', 150 );

    // Hide the response with a timeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#confirmation-response").hide('blind', function () {
            loadSourceContent()
        }, 500);
    }, 2500);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VayBF/) for a demo.

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400184/cache-php-generated-image-until-it-changes) question once as well.

Comment: Perfect!! And it makes sense too... Thank you Lobo!

Comment: As @Huangism mentioned, please go back and accept answers to your older questions (if you got the right answers), This will motivate others to help you out. Just know that everyone here is greedy for points. :-)